# How to Create, Read and Write a yaml file in Ubuntu using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am created a GUI in which I have a one code Editor. when we entered any yaml data into the editor and click on the save button then I want to create a yaml file on the ubuntu machine on /home/ubuntu location and the data entered by a user will be saved in that file.

How to do it any idea about it?